# Best way to setup an array of classes to ignore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following if statement in a jQuery script that checks if an image has a class of "ignore", and if so it will ignore it. `this` is an image the script found earlier within a specific section of my page:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('ignore')) {
 //do something
}
```

How can I set this up so that I can store an array of classes, and then have the if statement check against that array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an `Array` as you normally would and `push` whichever classes you want to ignore.

In your `if` statement do a `.not()` selector and pass in your `Array` values by calling the `join` function.

---

```
var classes = new Array(".ignore", ".something");

// on a single img

if(!$(this).is(classes.join(",")) {
    //do something to one
}

// on a collection of imgs

$("img").not(classes.join(", "));

$("img").not(classes.join(", ")).each(function(){
    // do something to one
});
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/hEsPd/1/

Comment: I have tried to implement this.  but it is not working in my case.  I failed to mention that there are multiple classes in my image like so `class="lazy aligncenter size-full wp-image-1293 ignore data-lazy-ready"`.  is that why it won't work?

Comment: it shouldn't matter. Can you post the code you're trying and some html?

Comment: my array: `var classes = new Array(".notThis", ".ignore");` this statement isn't working: `if($(this).not(classes.join(", "))) {   }` but this will: `if(!$(this).is(classes.join(", "))) {  }`

Comment: I found the problem. `.not()` is intended as a filter of sorts on a collection where `is()` looks at a single entity.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `is()` function instead of `hasClass()`. More info on the documentation : http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: `if (!$(this).is(".ignore"))`

Comment: I was writing it but @hunter did a better job in the end!

Comment: `not()` feels a bit better than `!is()`. I switched mine, but definitely works. +1!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!$(this).is("." + yourArray.join(", ."))) {
 //do something
}
```

or using Vanilla JS

```
var regex = new Regex("(" + yourArray.join("|") + ")");
if(!this.className.match(regex)) {
   //do something
}
```